# How to remove padding from images

Tags: html, css

```css
 * {

}

 body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}


/*  =====Header===== */
 header {
  display: inline;

}

 .logo {
  background-color: #dedede;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
  <header>
      <div class="navContainer">
        <a href=#>
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1fsTc5I.png" alt="headLogo" class="logo">
        </a>
      </div>
          <nav>
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </nav>
    </header>
```

So I have an image and it seems to me it has a padding of 32px around it and I dont want it, I already tried padding: 0; padding: 0!important; I am getting frustrated please help me mates! 
[I added a background of gray so you can see the padding of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb83R.png)

{Edit I added a background so you can see the padding}

Comment: The logo has a clear background.

Comment: where you want to put that image?

Comment: Could you please provide your HTML / CSS or a link to the image?

Comment: @user8190367 there is no padding in the fiddle bro.!

Comment: @user8190367 use this imgae https://imgur.com/a/18xM4

Answer (score 2):

If you look under the "Computed" tab when accessing dev-tools, you'll see this image has no padding at all. You just need to use photoshop to remove the extra white space around your text in the image, and you should be fine.

Comment: the image does not have any whitespace i removed using photshop

Comment: Please inspect your code image is showing extra space around photomagic text.